# Pass object value in form data to API?

Tags: reactjs, form-data

Here is the result of my backend API from POSTMAN:

I got two key here, which is `json`and also `itemFile`

[image]

```
   createItem(){

     const itemData = this.state;
     const selectedFile = this.state;

     const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('json', itemData)
        formData.append('itemFile', selectedFile)

        console.log(formData)


        fetch(`http://localhost:9000/api/item/submit`, 
         {
             method: 'post',
             body: formData
         }).then ((result) => {  
                 let responseJSON = result;
                 console.log(responseJSON);
                 });
      }
```

After that, I got the error of
**Unrecognized token 'object': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: (String)\"[object Object]\"; line: 1, column: 8]**

Is it I need to use JSON.Stringify? but how would I use it in form-data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itemData` in your code must be an object.

FormData append method's second argument should be a USVString or Blob (including subclasses such as File).

**If none of these are specified the value is converted to a string by calling `toString` method.**

```
formData.append('json', itemData)

formData.get('json')  // "[object Object]"
```

So, you need to use JSON.stringify before appended to formData

```
formData.append('json', JSON.stringify(itemData))
```